# Batch Script - Parenthesized echo of the word "Where" issue

Tags: batch-file

A while back I asked about [Batch Script Redirection Syntax](https://superuser.com/questions/1106951/batch-script-redirection-syntax) and received a nice answer. I've utilized the parenthesis `()` method more often to `echo` in batch scripts and redirect to files, etc.

I've run into an odd issue where it appears the word `Where` is not be able to be `echo`'d as that word literally and it seems it's interpreted as the [`Where`](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html) command being invoked instead.

---

*To keep this example simple, I've dumbed down the script logic to a much simpler version, but the **PowerShell** logic being `echo`'d could be much more complex than this.*

### Script Example

```
@ECHO ON

(
    ECHO [System.IO.DriveInfo]::GetDrives() ^| Where {$_.Name -like "C:\"}
)>> Outfile.txt

PAUSE
```

**Error**

> ```
> INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
> ```
>
> [image]

---

### What I've done

I troubleshot this a little and did some quick research and couldn't find a simple answer. Since I have not asked many questions on **SuperUser**, I figured this would be a good one potentially.

One thing in particular I tried was setting a variable as a string value of `Where` (i.e. `SET w=Where`) and then in the parenthesized `echo` commands I referenced that variable (i.e. `%w%`) in place of the word `Where` but the result is still the same error.

I also played around a little with `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` but it made no difference.

```
@ECHO ON
SET w=Where
(
    ECHO [System.IO.DriveInfo]::GetDrives() ^| %w% {$_.Name -like "C:\"}
)>> Outfile.txt
PAUSE
```

---

### The Workaround

I have simply not been using the parenthesized method for `echo`ing the word "`Where`" and I have just been utilizing the appended `>>` redirect to the file method on each `echo`'d line individually where "`where`" is involved. No big deal for this small example but a bigger deal for a larger script.

```
@ECHO ON
ECHO [System.IO.DriveInfo]::GetDrives() ^| Where {$_.Name -like "C:\"}>> Outfile.txt
PAUSE
```

---

### Correlated Questions

<sub>***Hmmmmm......***</sub>

1. What is causing this and what exactly is happening when this occurs?
2. Is there a way to allow the word (or string) "`Where`" to be used without the issue?

---

### Resources

- [Using parenthesis/brackets to group expressions](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html)
- [Where](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misdiagnosed the problem - WHERE has nothing to do with it.

You simply need to escape the closing parenthesis:

```
@ECHO ON

(
    ECHO [System.IO.DriveInfo]::GetDrives(^) ^| Where {$_.Name -like "C:\"}
)>> Outfile.txt

PAUSE
```

Comment: Actually, `where` is not completely irrelevant: it was `where.exe` that generated the error message `INFO: Could not find ...`. In other words, because of the questioner's syntax, `where` was taken as a command, rather than a clause.

Comment: @AFH - Interesting point. But I am a bit puzzled as to why where.exe is executing. I expected a syntax error because there was no `&` after the `)`. But some how the escaped `|` is allowing `Where` to be interpreted as a command.

Comment: Dave - I think that's the same thing that puzzled me and probably why I overlooked escaping the the closing parenthesis.

Comment: @AFH - I've started a discussion about this oddity at http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8198

Comment: @Facebook - ditto

Comment: @ITSnuggles - There are two separate issues here. The fundamental problem was the unescaped `)`. Unless you are a batch geek like me, that is all you need worry about. The other obscure issue (a newly discovered quirk) is you cannot escape a special character token like `|` immediately following closure of a parenthesized block. That shouldn't be  an issue because I'm not aware of any valid syntax that uses an escaped token after closure. But the behavior violates [our current understanding of batch parsing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/1012053). *(Continued in next comment)*

Comment: I started a [dostips discussion about this new discovery](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8198),  and PenPen was simply advancing a [theory as to a possible flawed internal design of cmd.exe](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8198#p54553) that might explain the source of the obscure behavior. I cannot follow the logic of his theory enough to draw any conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one other option for you.  This doesn't require you to escape the parentheses or the pipe. When you redirect the NUL device to the `SET /P` command it writes the prompt string to stdout.  The one caveat to this is that `SET /P` doesn't write out a carriage return and line feed so you need an empty `ECHO.` to output the CRLF.

```
@ECHO OFF

(
<nul set /p "=[System.IO.DriveInfo]::GetDrives() | Where {$_.Name -like "C:\"}" &echo.
echo another line
)>Outfile.txt

notepad Outfile.txt
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 2):

For what it’s worth,
it seems that, after a `)`, CMD interprets `^|` as `|`:

```
C:\> (echo 1.The && echo 2.quick && echo 3.brown && echo 4.fox) ^| find "q"
2.quick
```