# Windows: how to pipe cd and where command

Tags: windows, command-line

In the Windows console

1. By `where` command, I'll find a file within `%PATH`
   e.g: `where cmd` -> `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`
2. With result above, I'll move there

**I tried...**

- search in google
- `cd %(...`
- `where <F> | cd`

**I think...**

- `where` command returns the directory and filename
- So, is there any command to return just the directory?
- and, what if it is, how to pipe which `cd` command
- or, do I need a some script?

Comment: Potentially similar: https://superuser.com/questions/1261588/batch-script-parenthesized-echo-of-the-word-where-issue... Probably not though but just in case

Answer (score 5):

#### How do I use `where` to `cd` to the directory where the command is found?

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('where %1') do (
  cd /d %%~dpi
  )
```

Example usage:

```
test cmd
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [CD Change Directory - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [For - Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Parameters / Arguments - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)